# Difference between object and function object | How to test for?

Tags: javascript, jquery

See this fiddle for a good example of a function object and the object that `$()` returns.

http://jsfiddle.net/tFhFD/3/

Reference:

http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js

Comment: Functions are prime class objects in js.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, that's not how you create a function object, that's how you create an object.

To create a function object, you just create a function. For example:

```
var function_object = function(){};
```

Or:

```
function F(){}
var function_object = F;
```

As a function is also an object, you can add properties to it just like any other object:

```
function_object.myProperty = 42;

function_object.doSomething = function(){};
```

Comment: so when you call new on your function object...you get an object.

Comment: @HiroProtagonist: Exactly. The `new` keyword is used to create an object that gets the prototype that is defined for the function, and the function initialises the object, but it works with any function even if the function doesn't have anything specificed in the prototype and doesn't initialise anything.

Comment: So...in the updated fiddle I posted above, what does `this` refer to?

Comment: @HiroProtagonist: When a function is used to create an object, `this` refers to the newly created object. (Note that the `init` function is put in the prototype for the function, but it's not used as a method for the object.)

Comment: Well how is jQuery suppose to work then...if jQuery returns an object created by `jQuery.prototype.init()`....`$()`...returns `new jQuery.prototype.init();`

Comment: @HiroProtagonist: You can use a function declared anywhere, for example a local function: http://jsfiddle.net/Guffa/tFhFD/4/, or the $A function itself could do both things: http://jsfiddle.net/Guffa/tFhFD/5/